# Is $\frac{(c-a)}{(c-b)}>\frac{\exp(-at)-\exp(-ct)}{\exp(-bt)-\exp(-ct)}$?

Tags: inequality, exponential-function

Suppose, $$a<b<c$$ then is $$\frac{(c-a)}{(c-b)}>\frac{\exp(-at)-\exp(-ct)}{\exp(-bt)-\exp(-ct)}$$ for all $t>0$?

Comment: exp$(-at)$ is best written in LaTeX as  \$e^{-at}\$ to look like $e^{-at}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is exactly the other way round which can be seen using the [generalized mean value theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CauchysMean-ValueTheorem.html) (GMVT):

$$\frac{\exp(-at)-\exp(-ct)}{\exp(-bt)-\exp(-ct)}= \underbrace{\frac{\exp(-ct)}{\exp(-ct)}}_{=1}\cdot \frac{\exp((c-a)t)-1}{\exp((c-b)t)-1}$$ $$ \stackrel{GMVT: 0<\tau <t}{=}\frac{(c-a)\exp((c-a)\tau)}{(c-b)\exp((c-b)\tau)} = \frac{(c-a)}{(c-b)}\cdot\underbrace{\exp((b-a)\tau)}_{>1} \color{blue}{>} \frac{(c-a)}{(c-b)}$$